# How to get Hyperion Smart View For Office Version add-in?

Tags: excel, excel-addins, hyperion, essbase, vba

Can you get the version of Hyperion SmartView installed using visual basic code for excel ?

I need to get a string output with the version number or something that looks like this -> 11.1.2.2.000

regards

Answer (score 1):

[The Smart View for Office Developer's Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E40248_01/epm.1112/smart_view_developer.pdf) explains the use of HypGetVersion() on Page 44.  It will, among other things, return the version.